# How to define periodicity of orbits for general group actions?

Tags: lie-groups, dynamical-systems, homogeneous-spaces

Let $H$ be a topological group acting on a topological space $X$. Is there a general definition of periodicity in this case? Write $X=G/\Gamma$ and consider the orbit $Hg\Gamma$, what does it mean for the orbit $Hg\Gamma$ to be periodic? If there is an abstract definition, I also wish to know the intuition behind it.

Comment: Well, for instance you may require the orbit to be compact. If $H$ is the group of real numbers or is a countable group you get, respectively, a circular or finite orbit.

Comment: Another option is to require the $H$-orbit to have finite volume (with respect to the projection of the Haar measure to $H/H_x$). Both notions appear naturally in the context of $H$-orbits on $G/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of a Lie group $G$ and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ (e.g. in Ratner's work).  However, I do not think anybody uses "periodic" terminology.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(dynamics)):

> For a general dynamical system, especially in homogeneous dynamics, when one has a "nice" group $G$ acting on a probability space $X$ in a measure-preserving way, an orbit $G.x \subset X$ will be called periodic (or equivalently, closed) if the stabilizer $\text{Stab}_{G}(x)$ is a lattice inside $G$.